# IronPython Script debugging

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython

I have a .NET application and there is an IronPython script tab-page. Scripts work properly, but I would strongly like to have a possibility to debug them 
right in the application and to toggle breakpoints.

Are there any solutions of this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing an Iron Python debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493557/writing-an-iron-python-debugger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an IronPython debugger [here](https://github.com/devhawk/ipydbg) and there is a series of blogs about creating it [here](http://devhawk.net/2009/02/27/writing-an-ironpython-debugger-introduction/).